# How to import my reducers to reducers.spec.js?

Tags: javascript, react-redux

When i run application - everything is OK. But when i run tests - it fail with error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier ({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import actions from '../LoginPage/actions'

My reducers.spec.js file:

```
import reducer from '../LoginPage/reducers';

const state = { user: [], isLoading: false };

describe('Login reducer', () => {
    it('should return initial state', () => {
        expect(reducer(undefined, {})).toEqual([
            {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false
            }]);
    });
    })
})
```

My reducers.js file:

```
const requestSignIn = 'REQUEST_SIGN_IN';
const receiveSignIn = 'RECEIVE_SIGN_IN';

const initialState = { user: [], isLoading: false};

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
    state = state || initialState;

    if (action.type === requestSignIn) {
        return {
            ...state,
            isLoading: true
        };
    }

    if (action.type === receiveSignIn) {
        return {
            ...state,
            user: action.user,
            isLoading: false
        };
    }

    return state;
};
```

It doesn't matter what i try to import. I think exactly import doesn't work.

Comment: can you add reducers.js file to your question so we can see what is the issue?

Comment: change export const reducer   to export default function reducer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options to resolve this issue :

- you need to change `export const reducer` to `export default (state, action) =>`  in  `reducers.js`.

or

- in `reducers.spec.js` change `import reducer from '../LoginPage/reducers';` to `import { reducer} from '../LoginPage/reducers';`

for further information you can read more about [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)  in MDN website.

Comment: I've already tried. It doesn't work.

In first case:
' import reducer from '../LoginPage/reducers';
           ^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)'



In second case:
 'import { reducer } from '../LoginPage/reducers';
           ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)'

Comment: do you have any .babelrc file?

Comment: No, I haven't any .babelrc file